# Splitting data in unix

Tags: unix, awk, cut

I have a DDL command with 300 plus fields and I need to separate the fields and datatypes separately and store them into an excel spreadsheet.Some of the data types are having spaces in between.Here is my sample data as below.

**What I have tried**

```
cut -f2 sample.txt | grep -e "^$" -v > sample1.txt
cut -f1 -d" " sample1.txt > fields.txt
```

I am able to get column1 from input file but how do I get the data type field separately and NOT NULL constraint separately.Also if there is no NOT NULL constraint the output file should have NULL value instead.

**INPUT**

```
SUPPLIER_PROC_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
BTCH_NBR INTEGER NOT NULL
RX_BTCH_SUPPLIER_SEQ_NBR INTEGER NOT NULL
CORRN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
RX_CNT BYTEINT NOT NULL
DATA_TYP_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL
DATA_PD_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL
CYC_DT DATE NOT NULL
BASE_DT DATE NOT NULL
DATA_LOAD_DT DATE NOT NULL
DATA_DT DATE NOT NULL
SUPPLIER_DATA_SRC_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL
RX_CHNL_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL
MP_IMS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
MP_LOC_ID NUMERIC(30)
MP_IMS_ID_ACTN_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL
NPI_ID BIGINT
NPI_ID_ACTN_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL
MP_DEA_NBR NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(9)
MP_DEA_NBR_ACTN_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

*Fields*

```
SUPPLIER_PROC_ID
BTCH_NBR
RX_BTCH_SUPPLIER_SEQ_NBR
CORRN_ID
RX_CNT
DATA_TYP_CD
DATA_PD_CD
CYC_DT
BASE_DT
DATA_LOAD_DT
DATA_DT
SUPPLIER_DATA_SRC_CD
RX_CHNL_CD
MP_IMS_ID
MP_LOC_ID
MP_IMS_ID_ACTN_CD
NPI_ID
NPI_ID_ACTN_CD
MP_DEA_NBR
MP_DEA_NBR_ACTN_CD
```

*Data-types*

```
BIGINT
INTEGER
INTEGER
INTEGER
BYTEINT
BYTEINT
BYTEINT
DATE
DATE
DATE
DATE
BYTEINT
BYTEINT
INTEGER
NUMERIC(30)
BYTEINT
BIGINT
BYTEINT
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(9)
BYTEINT
```

*Not-nulls*

```
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL
NOT NULL

NOT NULL

NOT NULL

NOT NULL
```

Comment: did you tried something or do you want someone to do you job?

Comment: You are missing a "NOT NULL" from your output listing.

Comment: Why is this going into separate files? Why not "CSV" the data and then, if separate treatment is required, just do that in the spreadsheet? A file of 300 lines of "NOT NULL" interspersed with a few blanks is going to be very difficult to check for validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to solve. You could do it by looking for "NULL" at the end of each line and treat the input accordingly:

*parse.awk*

```
$NF == "NULL" { null_flag = 1 }
{
  # first column goes to "fields"
  print $1 > "fields"

  # second column through NF or NF-2 goes to "data-types"
  for(i=2; i <= NF-(null_flag ? 2: 0); i++)
    printf "%s ", $i > "data-types"
  printf "\n" > "data-types"

  # "NOT NULL" or "" goes to "not-nulls" based on the null_flag
  print (null_flag ? "NOT NULL": "") > "not-nulls"
}
{ null_flag = 0 }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
fields                    data-types                      not-nulls
~~~~~~                    ~~~~~~~~~~                      ~~~~~~~~~
SUPPLIER_PROC_ID          BIGINT                          NOT NULL
BTCH_NBR                  INTEGER                         NOT NULL
RX_BTCH_SUPPLIER_SEQ_NBR  INTEGER                         NOT NULL
CORRN_ID                  INTEGER                         NOT NULL
RX_CNT                    BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
DATA_TYP_CD               BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
DATA_PD_CD                BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
CYC_DT                    DATE                            NOT NULL
BASE_DT                   DATE                            NOT NULL
DATA_LOAD_DT              DATE                            NOT NULL
DATA_DT                   DATE                            NOT NULL
SUPPLIER_DATA_SRC_CD      BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
RX_CHNL_CD                BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
MP_IMS_ID                 INTEGER                         NOT NULL
MP_LOC_ID                 NUMERIC(30)                     
MP_IMS_ID_ACTN_CD         BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
NPI_ID                    BIGINT                          
NPI_ID_ACTN_CD            BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
MP_DEA_NBR                NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(9)   
MP_DEA_NBR_ACTN_CD        BYTEINT                         NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk sample.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
{
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {

        if ($i FS $(i+1) == x=("NOT NULL")) {
            break
        }

        r = (r ? r FS : "") $i
    }

    print $1 > "fields"
    print r > "data-types"
    print ($0 ~ x ? x : "") > "not-nulls"

    r = ""
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i FS $(i+1) == x=("NOT NULL")) break; r = (r ? r FS : "") $i } print $1 > "fields"; print r > "data-types"; print ($0 ~ x ? x : "") > "not-nulls"; r = "" }' sample.txt
```

In my testing, this generates three files each with the desired output. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear, but it looks like you just want:

```
awk '{ print $1 > "fields"; print $2 > "data-types" }'
```

Comment: Hi William.. thanks for the reply.But my question is simple.I need all the fields in one column,data types in one column(but if you see a data type field like NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(56) it should be considered as a data type and 3rd column should contain NOT NULL and NULL values(if there is no constraint) )

Comment: You need to provide a rigorous description of a "data type" and a "field".  Once you have that, you are essentially done.

Comment: I added the sample ip/op William

Comment: Data type tells whether the field is numerical or integer or character or byte whereas FIELD is a column name present in a table.(Oracle table)